# having problems expanding the space of one partition on a disk

Tags: debian, partition

I currently have a VM which has 50 GB of space. I increased it to 100 GB and booted the Ubuntu Live CD.

I did the following

1. Deleted the partition `/dev/vda1`
2. Readded it with all blocks
3. `resize2fs /dev/vda1` and it did it's job
4. rebooted

Now, df -h shows me it's still 50 GB. Is there anything I missed? The `/dev/vda` disk is 107 GB.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there another partition that is adjecent to partition #1.  I ask because you can only expand (in place) if the area is contiguous to what was there before.  You might want to show the fdisk for the disk /dev/vda.

Comment: Screenshot has been added to the initial post.

Comment: Yes, without first deleting the swap partition, the extended partition definition, deleting the initial paritition and then doing the stuff in reverse...you're not going to get any larger than what you got now!

Comment: Alright, is it safe the delete these partitions, resizing the filesystem and then recreate them?

Comment: @Devator assuming it's not a live system or you've at least disabled swap it would be ok, but I think mdpc missed that you've supposedly already grown the partition, but `resize2fs` doesn't report the same number of blocks as `fdisk`

Comment: @DerfK and mdpc I just tested it on a machine, and works perfectly (using gParted with Ubuntu live cd)! Cheers!

Comment: @derfk, are the sizes given in fdisk always the same as reported in resize2fs?  I'm not so sure that is true.

Comment: @mdpc neither am I, but it seems like your idea worked, so it must be the case that 1) vda1 was originally not made larger because vda2/vda5 was in the way and 2) `resize2fs` blocks are different from `fdisk` blocks so even though it looked like the partition is larger than the filesystem, it wasn't.